How to disable the flutter default List.generate Dropdown effect
enter image description here    List.generate( controller.skills.length,
(index) => buildSkillWidget(index))
I'm trying to disable the default dropdown effect of listView when we set the data. I have tried different solutions but non of them work. Is there any way we can disable this dropdown effect.

please,provide a gif or image

@IldebertoVasconcelos PFA gif.
